# Make a makefile for multiple java files within the same package

Tags: java, makefile

For homework I had to create some program, but the professor wants us to have a makefile to compile and run the program.  I did some research but all I could find was instructions for c programs.  I am unsure about how to do it for java.

the package name for the program is `sysoft`

the `.java` files are inside `src/sysoft/`

the `.java` files' names are `fileReader.java`, `hashTable.java`, and `mainClass.java`

and the program should take one argument

I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: Check this link: http://www.cs.swarthmore.edu/~newhall/unixhelp/javamakefiles.html and this http://profesores.elo.utfsm.cl/~agv/elo329/Java/javamakefile.html

Comment: Probably offtopic question: why not use tools that are more java like? ant/maven? gradle?

Comment: you have a terribly ignorant professor, `Maven` or 'Gradle` are the current build systems for Java used by professionals. `make` never has been and never will be. You are not learning anything that will make you valuable to an employer. **Please tell them you are paying them to teach you how to be valuable to future employers and they are not doing that for you with ignorant requirements like this.**

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution at: http://www.cs.swarthmore.edu/~newhall/unixhelp/javamakefiles.html

```
JFLAGS = -g
JC = javac
.SUFFIXES: .java .class
.java.class:
    $(JC) $(JFLAGS) $*.java

CLASSES = \
    main.java

default: classes

classes: $(CLASSES:.java=.class)
```